# pgfplots and exp(x) throws error: Dimension too large

Tags: tikz-pgf

I hope, someone can help me. I've the following problem:

I want to draw a Graph like this
[image: exp Problem]

The picture shows the following graphs: exp(x), ln(x), x

my code is:

```
\begin{tikzpicture} 
    \draw[ultra thin,color=gray] (-0.1,-0.1) grid (5,5);
    \draw[->] (-0.2,0) -- (5.2,0) node[below] {$x$}; 
    \draw[->] (0,-0.2) -- (0,5.2) node[above] {$y$};

    \draw (0,0)--(5,5);

    \draw[color=blue, samples=150, thick, domain=0:1.6095]   
            plot (\x,{exp(\x r)}) node[right] {$f(x) = exp x$};
    \draw[color=cyan, samples=150, thick, domain=1:5]
            plot (\x,{ln(\x r)}) node[right] {$f(x) = ln x$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

My LaTeX Compliler throws me the follwoing message:

> plot (\x,{exp(\x r)})
>
> node[right] {$f(x) = exp x$}; I can't work with sizes bigger than about 19 feet. Continue and I'll use the
>
> largest value I can.

The Domain Value for exp(x) is 1.6095 because exp(1.6095) = 5

I hope, you can help me.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your question was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your question title it mentions `pgfplots` but you don't use it. And if you don't use `r`(radian) indicator everything runs smoothly.  I'll take the easy way out by just giving a simple `pgfplots` example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{axis}[xmin=-0.5,xmax=5,ymin=-0.5,ymax=5,no markers,samples=50,grid=both]
\addplot {exp(x)};
\addplot {ln(x)};
\addplot {x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Please see the [`pgfplots`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/pgfplots) manual for a lot more.